# Deleting with self-referential foreign key in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

With a table with a self-referential foreign key:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tree (  
    id INTEGER,
    parent_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)  
);

ALTER TABLE tree 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tree
   FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
   REFERENCES tree(id);

INSERT INTO tree (id, parent_id)
VALUES (1, null),
       (2, 1),
       (3, 1),
       (4, 2),
       (5, null),
       (6, 5);
```

I wish to delete a branch by recursively traversing the tree as I may not use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE branch (id, parent_id) AS (
      SELECT id, parent_id
      FROM tree
      WHERE id = 1 -- Delete branch with root id = 1

      UNION ALL SELECT c.id, c.parent_id
      FROM tree c -- child
      JOIN branch p -- parent
            ON c.parent_id = p.id
)
DELETE FROM tree t
USING branch b
WHERE t.id = b.id;
```

Is it safe to do it with a common table expression in Postgres, or do I have to worry about the order in which the records are deleted? Will Postgres delete all rows as a single set, or one by one?

If the answer is dependent on version, from which version is the deletion safe?

Comment: Note: in non-trivial cases, you really need an index supporting `FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't have to worry about the order in the select.

Foreign keys (unlike unique constraints) are evaluated *per statement*, not per row. And a common table expression is still a **single** statement, even if you have multiple SELECTs and DELETEs in it.

So if all constraints are still valid when the statement finishes, everything is OK.

---

You can easily see this with the following simple test:

```
CREATE TABLE fk_test
(
  id          integer PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id   integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES fk_test (id)
);

INSERT INTO fk_test (id, parent_id) 
VALUES 
  (1, null),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 2),
  (4, 1);
```

So the following obviously works, even if the IDs are specified in the "wrong" order:

```
DELETE FROM fk_test
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

The following *also* works - showing that a CTE is still a single statement:

```
with c1 as (
  delete from fk_test where id = 1
), c2 as (
  delete from fk_test where id = 2
), c3 as (
  delete from fk_test where id = 3
)
delete from fk_test where id = 4;
```

Comment: Nice. In fact, OP's tree `INSERT` statement can also forward reference nodes further down the list, e.g. `(6, 5)` could be the first node in the list.

Comment: Great! Good news, and great explanation. Thanks for clarifying it!